# Failed to initialize conda directories when trying to install Anaconda 3

Tags: python, anaconda3

I'm trying to install Anaconda 3 2023.03 and can't get anywhere with it. I get an error that says "Failed to initialize conda directories". I tried installing as an administrator. If I do this the install goes through but the system doesn't recognise the install anywhere. If I type "where conda" into the terminal it says it doesn't exist. I had a previous installation of python 3.11 which I deleted every trace I could find (I'm not competent to go fishing around the registry without clear instructions here) but still no joy.

I've only just started learning Python and need to install Anaconda to follow along with my Udemy course, so please dumb it down for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Anaconda, choose to install it for "All Users" instead of "Just for Me"

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34524535)